# Summing two columns then subtracting the sums

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, sum

Here is my table.

```
pk |  transactionID
   |  description
   |  transactionDate
   |  transactionAmount
   |  accountRecieve
   |  accountSend
```

Those are my columns. I need to find the balance given an accountNumber through a query. To do this I have to SUM transactionAmount where accountSend = 127 and then SUM transactionAmount where accountRecieve = 127 and then subtract the first sum from the second sum and show it in one result.

I can explain it but I have no idea how to execute this in SQL. Can anyone please help.

Comment: For future reference the correct tag for Access is `ms-access`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IIF(accountReceive = 127, transactionAmount, 0)) -
    SUM(IIF(accountSend = 127, transactionAMount, 0)) AS diff
FROM yourTable;
```

The idea is to just make a single pass over the entire table, summing the transaction amount using the two criteria.

Comment: Access does not support CASE

Comment: @RhysSwansbra I must have missed the Access tag.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also express this using `switch`:

```
SELECT SUM(SWITCH(accountReceive = 127, transactionAmount
                  accountSend = 127, - transactionAMount, 0,
                  1=1, 0
                 )
          ) AS diff
FROM yourTable;
```

This only uses one `SUM()` and is more analogous to using `CASE` in other databases.